# Add missing full-stops at the end of a text block

Tags: python, regex, string, tags, punctuation

Currently, I'm trying to prepare some texts for my machine learning task in python3.

The input data is a single long string and has the following format:

```
<SPEAKER gender="female" id="1" name="unknown"> sentence_1. sentence_2? ... sentence_n, </SPEAKER><SPEAKER gender="male" id="2" name="unknown"> sentence_1. sentence_2? ... sentence_n </SPEAKER><SPEAKER gender="female" id="1" name="unknown"> sentence_1. sentence_2? ... sentence_n; </SPEAKER> ...
```

It consists of multiple "text blocks", starting `<SPEAKER ...>` and ending `</SPEAKER>` with tags.
As you can see, sometimes the last sentence within a block (sentence_n) is missing a full-stop `.` or the sentence end with a comma `,` or semicolon `;`.

The current problem is, when I cleanse the provided string and delete the tags, the last sentence (sentence_n) of a block and the first sentence (sentence_1) of the following block merge. I just want to avoid this. I want to the sentences to end with punctuation to be able to split the total string sentence-wise in my later text preprocessing steps.

Therefore, I would like to check the LAST character of the LAST sentence (sentence_n) of every block and

1. add a full-stop if it's missing
2. replace a comma or semicolon with full-stop
3. if a full-stop already exists, just keep it

Thank you very much in advance!

Edit1: It does not have to be a regex solution. Since I handle thousands of such strings, performance is still important.

Edit2: Specified the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can indeed use a regular expression:

```
import re 

s = re.sub(r"([;,.])?(\s*</SPEAKER>)", r".\2", s)
```

This captures the `;`, `,` or `.` when it is the last non-white-space character in the tag, or -- if not possible -- captures the empty string at the spot where the point should occur. In either case it replaces that capture with a point.

Then apply your solution for removing the tags.